# Is there a command to halt the interpreter in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm looking for an expression that will cause the interpreter to exit when it is evaluated.

I've found lots of implementation-specific ones but none in the HyperSpec, and I was wondering if there were any that I wasn't seeing defined in the specification. I've found that `(quit)` is recognized by both CLISP and SLIME, and `(exit)` is recognized only by CLISP, but I can't find any documentation that references either of these.

Comment: It is implementation specific if there is an interpreter and if Lisp code runs interpreted. Most Common Lisp implementations provide a compiler. In implementations like SBCL there is only a compiler and no interpreter. CCL compiles everything by default. It is like asking how to shut down the Diesel engine of cars, when there are most cars having not a Diesel engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [ASDF library called shut-it-down](http://verisimilitudes.net/2017-12-30) that provides a `quit` function that works by just having cases for the common CL implementations.

Answer (score 25):

Since most Lisps import a quit function into CL-USER, CL-USER::QUIT is a good guess without knowing the implementation specific package where it is.

```
(cl-user::quit)
```

Note the two colons, since QUIT does not need to be exported from the CL-USER package.

Answer (score 20):

As far as I know, this is not covered by the Spec, and you will have to use the implementation-specific solutions, or maybe try and look if someone has already written a trivial-quit lib (or start one on [CLiki](http://www.cliki.net)).

If you only care about interactive use, `,q` in SLIME will always do the right thing. Otherwise, you may use read-time conditionals like this:

```
(defun my-quit ()
  #+sbcl (sb-ext:quit)
  #+clisp (ext:exit)
  #+ccl (ccl:quit)
  #+allegro (excl:exit)) ;; and so on ...
```

[`#+`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dhq.htm) checks, if the following symbol is in `*features*`. If not, the following form will be treated as white-space. (There is also [`#-`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dhr.htm) for the opposite).

Comment: Here's a google code search that points to what SLIME uses in each of these cases: http://google.com/codesearch?q=%22defimplementation+quit-lisp%22

Comment: Awesome. Any idea if there's a catch-all I can use, like "if none of these features are found, try running `(exit)`"?

Comment: haldean: Not sure what you mean.  You can try running anything you want.  :-)  Since it's not standardized, and they don't seem to be at all consistent, I don't know how you'd decide what to pick.  Most trivial-* libraries, IIRC, signal an error if you're using an unknown compiler.

Comment: haldean, probably a bit late, but you can do: #-(or sbcl clisp ccl ...) (exit)    at the bottom of all your #+ forms

Comment: FWIW, in case one wishes to exit with a particular exit code using SBCL, one can instead do, e.g., `(sb-ext:exit :code 1)` -- that will exit with exit code 1.  See https://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Exit for more detail.  (I know this is only an SBCL case, and not a direct answer to the question, but it's what I was looking for when I found this question and answer, so adding it as a comment.)

Answer (score 7):

There is no standard way to exit a CL environment. To find out how to do it in the implementation you're using, read its documentation.

In sbcl, `(sb-ext:quit)` will do the trick. For clisp, it's `(ext:exit)`. The clisp documentation for the command is at http://clisp.sourceforge.net/impnotes.html#quit

Answer (score 4):

You can use `(uiop:quit)`.  This is included in most lisps.