# How to use quick lisp in batch mode of CLISP

Tags: common-lisp, clisp, quicklisp

I could use packages installed with quick lisp:
[Using packages installed from quicklisp with clisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974020/using-packages-installed-from-quicklisp-with-clisp/20974264#20974264)

I tried to execute the lisp code that uses packages using command line. The code is

```
(ql:quickload "yacc")
(use-package 'yacc)
```

When I tried it with `clisp ex.lisp`, I got this error message:

```
*** - READ from #<INPUT BUFFERED FILE-STREAM CHARACTER #P"ex.lisp" @2>: there
      is no package with name "QL"
```

I had to use `clisp < ex.lisp` to load the package.

What makes the difference between the two approaches? Is `clisp < ex.lisp` the only way to use packages in command line?

I found this [How to use quicklisp when CL program is invoked as a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229526/how-to-use-quicklisp-when-cl-program-is-invoked-as-a-shell-script), but it's not for clisp.

Comment: I suspect clisp handles init files differently in interactive and non-interactive mode, so your quicklisp setup isn't loaded when you launch with an argument.

Comment: @molbdnilo -- I would second that. According to the `CLISP` man page, "No RC file will be executed", when the interpreter is started as `clisp script.lisp`. The OP should use the `-i` option to cause `setup.lisp` to be loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a c.lisp that executes and exits the calculator.lisp.

```
(load "calculator.lisp")
;(in-package #:yacc-calculator)
(yacc-calculator:calculator)
(ext:exit)
```

Run clisp with -i: `clisp -i c.lisp`.

#### Reference

- [Is there a command to halt the interpreter in Common Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425400/is-there-a-command-to-halt-the-interpreter-in-common-lisp)
- http://dilawarnotes.wordpress.com/2011/03/27/clisp-in-batch-mode/